# Docker Share Data Between Containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have 3 docker images and each one of them includes different dataset. I'm trying to create a volume and then mount those 3 dataset containers to that volume. Then bind a container created from an another major image and use those 3 separate datasets from same place (which is the major one).

Here is what filesystems of each of these three containers looks like:

```
container1: /datasets/xxx/01.jpg...
container2: /datasets/yyy/01.jpg...
container3: /datasets/zzz/01.jpg...
```

My docker command flow is looks like this:

```
docker volume create my-data
docker run -ti -d -v my-data:/datasets dataset/xxx:latest
docker run -ti -d -v my-data:/datasets dataset/yyy:latest
docker run -ti -d -v my-data:/datasets dataset/zzz:latest
```

And lastly, the major one:

```
docker run -ti -v my-data:/datasets major-application/app:latest
```

After these steps, when I do `ls /datasets` inside the container created from major-application image, I only see `/datasets/xxx/01.jpg...` directory. Also no luck with the `--volumes-from` command either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is extracting the datasets into a new image a possibility? Do you have a copy of the `Dockerfile` used to build `dataset/abc:latest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about mounting the xxx, yyy, zzz folders to different volumes like this:

```
docker run -ti -d -v my-data-xxx:/datasets/xxx dataset/xxx:latest
docker run -ti -d -v my-data-yyy:/datasets/yyy dataset/yyy:latest
docker run -ti -d -v my-data-zzz:/datasets/zzz dataset/zzz:latest
```

And then the major one:

```
docker run -ti -v my-data-xxx:/datasets/xxx -v my-data-yyy:/datasets/yyy -v my-data-zzz:/datasets/zzz major-application/app:latest
```

Comment: Looks like this is the most practical way to achieve what I try to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Naming your containers and mounting volumes at different directories, you can use the `--volumes-from` to mount the volumes from each of the containers:

```
docker run --rm -it --name xxx -d -v xxx:/datasets/xxx dataset/xxx:latest
docker run --rm -it --name yyy -d -v yyy:/datasets/yyy dataset/yyy:latest
docker run --rm -it --name zzz -d -v zzz:/datasets/zzz dataset/zzz:latest
```

**Note**: you don't have to explicitly `create` the volumes.

Then using the `--volumes-from`: `docker run --rm -it --volumes-from xxx --volumes-from yyy --volumes-from zzz ubuntu:18.04 ls -alF /datasets`

If the datasets are static in the images (`dataset/abc:latest`) then you could extend the `major-application/app:latest` image with the datasets, example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM dataset/xxx:latest as xxx
FROM dataset/yyy:latest as yyy
FROM dataset/zzz:latest as zzz
FROM major-application/app:latest
VOLUME [/datasets]
COPY --from=xxx /datasets/xxx /datasets/xxx
COPY --from=yyy /datasets/yyy /datasets/yyy
COPY --from=zzz /datasets/zzz /datasets/zzz
```

Comment: Huge thanks for the Dockerfile part. This answer is more legitimate for me for further works which will be done with Dockerfile.